# React-native-camera face recognition isn't working for iOS, RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.accurate is undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-camera

I have a react-native application that uses **react-native-camera** with its **FaceDetection** functionality and was working smoothly for quite some time.
Lately it started to shut down unexpectedly every time you try to open camera in this app. Code wasn't change. And for android it still works fine.

I saw that react-native-camera became deprecated, but I'm not sure why it started causing this issue. Looks like some FaceDetection support broken or is missing.
I'm testing on iPhone 13 with iOS 15 (both device and simulator)

Here's the **exception** itself:

```
    ...
    in ForwardRef
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in o
    in Unknown
    in RCTView
    in RCTView
    in C
2022-05-01 16:38:35.567685+0200 AppName[34604:2942356] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'p.RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.accurate')
```

Here's usage:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Platform,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';
import {SVGIcon} from '../common/svg/SVG';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';
import Svg from 'react-native-svg';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import {CitySelect} from '../common/Types';
import {StyledText} from '../common/StyledText';
import {useUser} from '../common/UserData';
import {fontName, cities, isHigherDimension} from '../common/common';
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
...
<RNCamera
          ref={rnCamera}
          style={styles.preview}
          trackingEnabled
          captureAudio={false}
          useNativeZoom={true}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={flashMode}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onFacesDetected={facesDetected}
          faceDetectionMode={
            RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.accurate
          }></RNCamera>
```

Dependencied in my package.json

```
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^8.4.2",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
```

### What I tried to do

First of all, I tried to check those RNCamera.Constants Options that appears to be undefined. Here's the value

```
this one is empty
   "FaceDetection":{
   },
but this one is present
   "GoogleVisionBarcodeDetection":{
      "BarcodeMode":{
         "ALTERNATE":1,
         "INVERTED":2,
         "NORMAL":0
      },
      "BarcodeType":{
         
      }
   }
```

As well I tried to remove the line that is calling RNCamera.Constants.FaceDetection.Mode.accurate constant. Then I get `Exception thrown while executing UI block: -[FaceDetectorManagerMlkit setTracking:queue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281eb18e0`.

I started to migrate to latest react-native, I got too much errors, it failed in many places so I decided to put this option aside.

I do have the line `pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [  'FaceDetector']` in my pod file. I tried to reinstall pods/rebuild multiple times.

Somewhere I saw recommendations to use Xcode "legacy build system" - no luck.

I tried manual linking of react native camera, still no success, as well as unlinking and reinstalling.

I'd really like to keep the functionality of face detection, so I'm looking forward to any suggestions! What could be the reason, has something in iOS changed that might've caused it?

Comment: Okay, the issue was with me having 0 knowledge of iOS dev and messing up with pod file. I fixed it by moving `pod 'react-native-camera', path: '../node_modules/react-native-camera', subspecs: [
    'FaceDetectorMLKit'
  ]
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection'` from the top of pod file `def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})` to `target 'PolitScanMobileClient' do`. Apparently it's where it should have been from the very begging. Worthy note: after upgrading to react-native-camera 4.2.1 I changed 'Firebase/MLVision' dependency to 'GoogleMLKit/FaceDetection'